# jQuery Ajax Call refreshes the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have looked at suggested pages and used searched but cant find out solution. I have very simple code jQuery below, where it gets the IDs (array) of check-boxes and send to report.php page through Ajax, below is my code that works fine:

```
$('#report').submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "report.php",
        data: $('.ids:checked'),
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(data.success == 1) {
              //upon success
            } else {
              // upon error
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

however I want to include a textarea which as ID as message, below is my html code:

```
     <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

if I change the "data" variable and add "message" in it, it refreshes the page upon submit:

```
     data: {ids: $('.ids:checked'), message: $("#message").val(text)},
```

How can I receive both array of IDs and Message variables without refreshing the page and working with Ajax. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: There is no submit in your code so what do you mean with submit? There is nothing to receive in your Code so what do you mean with receive array and message? The $(„message“).val(text) does make absolut no sense because it sets the textarea content..

Comment: Sorry, I added the submit part, it was already there, I just want to receive "message" variable in POST alongwith the IDS array..

Comment: @Lazy: jQuery's `$.ajax` function doesn't refresh the page, something else must be doing that or the code must be failing in some way that causes it to no longer prevent the form submit.  Can you provide a more complete example demonstrating the problem?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  In the network panel of those tools, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  It's not really clear what data you expect in `ids` or `message` in this case, the former is just selecting elements and the latter is *setting* a value.

Comment: @Lazy By any change you are using button type="submit" instead of type="button"?

Comment: Thanks @David - there is no error shown in debugger console, but it only happens when I change this line: data: $('.ids:checked'), to data: {ids: $('.ids:checked'), message: $("#message").val(text)}, .. otherwise it works fine as expected but I only have IDs in $_POST..

Comment: yes @ZamAbdulVahid, my button code is: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Send Report</button>

Comment: @Lazy change type from "submit" to "button" and check.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your help, I really appreciate this friendly community. The problem was I had array of checkboxes IDs which when passing to data was creating problem, so I found the following solution

```
var IDs = $('.ids:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

and then pass this value

```
data: { ids: IDs, message:$("#message").val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the ajax call but the submit is refreshing the page. So change the submit-button in your form to an ordinary button with `type="button"`, listen for the click on that button (instead of the submit event) and prevent inputs to submit the form by pressing "*Enter*"

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="submit_button">submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit_button').on('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "report.php",
        data: $('.ids:checked'),
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(data.success == 1) {
              //upon success
            } else {
              // upon error
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a jQuery object as a data item to $.ajax will cause an error, `event.preventDefault();` will not get called, and then your form submits and reloads the page(or load another page).
If you want to see the error put `event.preventDefault();`
Use the `.val()` method to get values to pass in the data object to pass to $.ajax

```
$('#report').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "report.php",
        data: {ids: $('.ids:checked').val(), message: $("#message").val()},
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(data.success == 1) {
              //upon success
            } else {
              // upon error
            }
        }
    });
});
```